# How do you stop Webpack from outputting new CSS files on every save?

Tags: webpack, sass, postcss, css-loader, sass-loader

I am using Webpack to generate my JavaScript and also generate my CSS (from SASS) using a chain of loaders [sass-loader, postcss-loader, css-loader].

When I'm developing I run Webpack in watch mode `webpack --progress --watch` and I have noticed that every time I save a JavaScript file, Webpack is outputting brand new CSS files each time.

Although this is not causing me any problems, this doesn't seem very efficient and I was wondering if I had my config setup incorrectly, or is this just how Webpack does things? Is there a way to stop it from doing this?

Below is my Webpack config so you can see what I'm running.

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const preCSSPlugin = require('precss');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

const isProduction = (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production');


module.exports = {
  entry: {
    /*
      Sitewide assets
    */
    // Javascript
    'build/js/main.js': './static-src/js/',
    // CSS
    'build/css/main.css': './static-src/sass/main.scss',
  },
  devtool: isProduction ? 'cheap-source-map' : 'eval',
  output: {
    filename: '[name]',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build/'), // Output to the `build` directory.
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      // SASS
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: [
            // CSS
            // https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader
            {
              loader: 'css-loader',
              options: {
                importLoaders: 1,
                sourceMap: true,
              },
            },
            // Post CSS loader lets us use Autoprefixer for the CSS
            // https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader
            {
              loader: 'postcss-loader',
              options: {
                sourceMap: 'inline',
                plugins: () => [
                  preCSSPlugin,
                  autoprefixer, // Autoprefixer loads the browserlist from package.json
                ],
              },
            },
            // SASS loader
            // https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader
            {
              loader: 'sass-loader',
              options: {
                outputStyle: 'expanded',
                sourceMap: true,
              },
            },
          ],
        }),
      },

      // JS (Babel) - Loads options from .babelrc
      // https://github.com/babel/babel-loader
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    // Output CSS from SASS
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: '[name]',
      disable: false,
      allChunks: true,
    }),
    // Output common chunk JS
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'common',
      // (the commons chunk name)
      filename: 'build/common.js',
      // (the filename of the commons chunk)
      minChunks: 3,
      // (Modules must be shared between 3 entries)
    }),
  ],
};
```

Comment: Any reason why you are using `main.scss` as an entrypoint?

Comment: Yes, this setup is for a CMS website and not a single application. I need to have the ability to build the styles, regardless of the javascript.